# Probability of Collision [binary vector]

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-verification, logic, problem-solving

Given a collection of nonzero distinct binary vectors $x_1,..., x_m \in {0,1}^n$. To make look up faster, we hash them to vectors of length $p<n$ by means of a lienar mapping $x_i \rightarrow Ax_i$ where $A$ is a $p\times n$ matrix with 0-1 entries, and all computations are performed modulo 2.

Suppose the entries of the matrix are picked uniformly at random (each independent coin toss)...

1- If we were to pick any $1 \leq i < j \leq m $ what is the prob. that $x_i$ and $x_j$ hash to the same vector and we have a collision?

> My attempt: I think that this is similar to the birthday problem from
>   https://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/ but I'm really unsure that we are bringing in an exponential 'e'. I'd guess from that link that the probability of collision = 1 - prob(no collision). So P(collision )= $1- e^{-p*(p-1)/2m}$ =$1- e^{-2*(2-1)/2m}$ = $1- e^{-1/m}$. Is that correct or completely the wrong? ... or would you leave the answer in terms of p (I think we only pick one i and j so we can simplify here?

2- Prove that if $p \geq 2log_2 m$, then with probability atleast $\frac{1}{2}$ there are no collisions among the $x_i$.

> My attempt: I'd say I need the answer to above (which is why I was concerned) .... but we would need $\frac{1}{2} =$ P(No Collision) =$e^{-p*(p-1)/2m}$ ... but this is not simplifying to $log_2$ and instead would mean $2mln(\frac{1}{2})= -p^{2}-p$. which is wrong b/c I will have that ln follow around ...

Comment: sorry for you 1- why are you doing a birthday problem type argument? when you  are just asking about a particular x_i being hashed to a particular x_j or am I reading this incorrectly?

Comment: I thought birthday problem can tell you what prob. the x_i and x_j would collide... I'm guessing this is not the case (why not?)

Comment: I think your wording is wierd pick any $1 \leq i < j \leq m $  that means you fix a particular i,j  and ask if they collide which is not the same thing as there is a collision for some x_i,x_j

Comment: Whoops updated the problem to say $x_i$ and $x_j$ hash to the same vector , so then your answer makes sense :) of how to ge to $(2^p)^2 + 2^p$ let me just ask why are we comparing to the $ \geq 2^p$ is that the p(collision)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have 2^p in place of p in your formula then you get the correct answer
Since you are mapping into {0,1}^p each x_i gets sent to a random entry of {0,1}^p uniformly at random  so it's the birthday problem with 2^p birthdays and m persons so by your estimate
$\frac{1}{2} =$ P(No Collision) =$e^{-(2^p)*(2^p-1)/2m}$
$2mln(\frac{1}{2})= -(2^p)^{2}+(2^p)   $. 
which is closer
I think it's best if you use the theorem that you get probability about 0.5 if you have that the square root of the number of possible birthdays is equal to the number of people (once both are large enough)

Comment: Can I get the reason behind $\geq 2^p$ (originally problem statement says  P(no collision)$\geq \frac{1}{2}$  not the $2^p$?

Comment: sorry thats a typo

Answer (score 0):

Hints: Note that $Ax_i=Ax_j$ if and only if $A(x_i-x_j)=0$. By assumption $x_i-x_j\neq 0$ for $i\neq j$. So you can reduce your problem to determining the probability $Az=0$ for any $z\neq 0$. Can you show that each component of $Az$ is uniformly random in $\{0,1\}$, and that the components are independent?

If you can, this will imply the probability $Ax_i=Ax_j$ is $1/2^p$. By linearity of expectation, this means the expected number of collisions among all the $x_i$ is ${m \choose 2} 2^{-p}\leq \frac{m^2}{2\cdot 2^p}$. What happens when you plug in $p=2\log_2 m$? Why does this imply what you want about the probability of a collision?

Comment: Wow this looks like were getting at the answer. I just need a bit more help, how did you go from 1/2^p to (m 2) 2^-p <= m^2/(2*2^p) ... you mentioned linearity of expectation, can you help me out here.How can the expected value of 1/2^p become that inequality... After plugging in the p=2log_m in that inequality it gets to (m choose 2 ) is <= to 1/32  ... I'm guessing were supposed to end to m >= 1/2?